# Problem Setting Id variable - List has no rows for assignment

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, error-messages, list

Not sure if I'm doing something incorrectly, but I'm having an odd issue. Below is a sample of my code which works fine in an execute anonymous window, but errors when I try to run it in a test class. I will receive a 'List has no rows for Assignment error'. I receive the error on this line.

```
Id hardware = [Select Id from PriceBookEntry where isActive = true and Pricebook2.isStandard = true and Product2.Family = 'Hardware' limit 1].id;
```

Sample of code.

```
Campaign cp = new Campaign(Name='SupportTestCampaign', Goal__c='Exposure');     
insert cp;        
Account a = new Account(Name='Test');
insert a;
Contact c = new Contact(AccountID = a.Id, FirstName = 'TestFirst', LastName='TestLast', Email='test@test.com');
insert c;
Opportunity o = new Opportunity(AccountId = a.Id, name='SupportTest', StageName='test', Application_of_Interest__c='TV Distribution', CloseDate=Date.today()); 
insert o;
OpportunityContactRole oRole = new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId = c.Id, Role = 'End-User', OpportunityId = o.Id);      
insert oRole;

//I receive the error on the below line
Id hardware = [Select Id from PriceBookEntry where isActive = true and Pricebook2.isStandard = true and Product2.Family = 'Hardware' limit 1].id;

OpportunityLineItem ol = new OpportunityLineItem(PriceBookEntryId = hardware, Quantity = 1, UnitPrice = 1000, OpportunityId = o.Id);

insert ol; 
o.StageName = 'Closed Won';
update o;
```

Comment: did you create those records in your Test Methods?  In the test context, your test methods cannot see any organization data, so you must create any data you want to test upon

Comment: though i THOROUGHLY disagree with using (SeeAllData=true), you may find good use that tag on your test methods .  

More discussion:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164986/how-do-i-avoid-standard-price-not-defined-when-unit-testing-an-opportunitylineit

Comment: @amatorVitae check this doc : As per slaesforce docs : inserting a pricebook entry for a custom pricebook isn’t supported since this requires defining a standard pricebook. For such situations, annotate your test method with IsTest(SeeAllData=true) so that your test can access organization data. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_data_access.htm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating the Pricebookentry record 
see the link below for an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164986/how-do-i-avoid-standard-price-not-defined-when-unit-testing-an-opportunitylineit

Use @isTest (seeAllData=true) to get access to pricebook info

```
Product2 prod= new Product2(Name='Test Product',isActive=true);
insert prod;

Pricebook2 testpb = [select id from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = true];
         testpb.IsActive=true;

PricebookEntry one = new PricebookEntry();
    one.pricebook2Id = testpb .id;
    one.product2id = prod.id;
    one.unitprice = 1249.0;
    one.isactive = true;
    insert one;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. I need to go ahead and create a PriceBookEntry in the test class that will match the criteria I have in the controller.